# OpenGL ES - uv-scroll (GL_REPEAT) stops working when rendering second texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture2d

An issue about uv-scrolling and GL_REPEAT arised this morning for me when i started to render an (animating) sprite on top of the background texture.

In other -w word, it works fine to uv-scroll the background when i just use the background-texture. But as soon as I try to render another texture on top of the background, the uv-scroll stops working.

I am implementings ECS-pattern and I can see in the android studio debugger that the UVscrollComponent's updatefunction is working just fine but the texture (background) becomes static (not moving). As soon as I remove drawing the second texture (sprite) the uv-scrolling starts work again.

The filter I am currently using

```
 GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_GLES30.GL_LINEAR, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
 GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_GLES30.GL_LINEAR, GLES30.GL_LINEAR);
 GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES30.GL_REPEAT);
 GLES30.glTexParameteri(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES30.GL_REPEAT);
```

What could the problem be?

cincerely

Answer (score 1):

Note: the snippets presented are intended to use with OpenGL ES 2.0. You must translate them to OpenGL ES 3.0 to use with your android application.

It appears to be that in your code you didn't set the active texture to make operations.

In this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036068/how-to-manage-multiple-textures-in-opengl-es-2-0), the answer tells you need to bind the texture previously to operate with:

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[textureIndex]);
```

If you handle multi-texture operations, you must bind the correct active texture to operate with it.

It means, for example, if your shader accepts 2 textures, you must set both active textures prior to work with them.

`GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0` binds for the first texture used in the shader, and `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1`, for the second one. The standard fragment and vertex shaders lets you use simultaneously up to 32 textures, from `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0` to `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE31`.